# Can one adapt LabelEncoder to your needs?

Tags: machine-learning

For a binary classification, I am using `LabelEncoder`. Let the two targets be A and Non-A. I want to assign the value 1 to A and 0 to Non-A. Unfortunately, `LabelEncoder` is doing the opposite. I thus changed it by including code for that:

```
  from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
  labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
  dataset['Gene Label']=labelencoder.fit_transform(dataset['Gene Type'])

  dataset['Gene Label] = final_sfari_houskeeping1["Gene Type"].apply(lambda x:1 if (x=="A") else 0)
```

I am wondering, if, when I am inverse transforming, this leads to a problem ?

> ```
> combine=pd.DataFrame(labelencoder.inverse_transform(y_predict),data.index)
> ```

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I think you should not use LabelEncoder at all and use your own encoding and decoding instead, it's simpler and safer.